# form submit handler not getting invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I am trying to log a message from the submit handler..and it is not working..

**HTML CODE**

```
<body>
<div class="table">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" style="background: #ffffff ;color:black">ABC</div>
            <div class="td">123</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
        <form id="form1_id" name="sa" class="tr editing">
            <div class="td thead">test</div>
            <div class="td"><input type="number" id="sa_cr1" onchange="add('form1',1)"></div>
            <div class="td"><input type="number" id="sa_cr2" onchange="add('form1',2)"></div>
        </form>
        <form id="form2_id" name="bc" class="tr editing">
            <div class="td thead">test1</div>
            <div class="td"><input type="number" id="bc_cr1" onchange="add('form2', 1)"></div>
            <div class="td"><input type="number" id="bc_cr2" onchange="add('form2', 2)"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
     <button type="submit"  value="Store" onclick="submitForms();"> </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function submitForms(){
    $('#form1_id')[0].submit();
    return false;
}

$("#form1_id").on("submit", function(event) // I tried both "submit" and "onsubmit"
{
       console.log("Handler for .submit() called.");
       event.preventDefault(); 
});
function add(str, num){};
```

---

You can also view the output in
https://jsfiddle.net/mdnak/b3z3h3jn/
I basically want the        `console.log("Handler for .submit() called.");`
 to get called...please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submitbtn").click(function(){
    $('#form1_id').submit();
    return false;

});

$("#form1_id").submit(function(event)
{
      alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
       event.preventDefault(); 
});
function add(str, num){};

});
```

As you are uniquely selecting the #form1_id from, you can directly submit as above and no need to get first element of it as it wont give array of forms `$('#form1_id')[0]`

and replace below line

```
<button type="submit"  value="Store" onclick="submitForms();"> </button>
```

with

```
<button type="button" id="submitbtn"> store </button>
```

Comment: Thank you sir...It solved my problem!! But I still have to figure out why the  code in question, though it took a different way, didnt work...is it about the array..[0]..Thank you again!

Comment: There were couple of things I observed first one it that `$('#form1_id')[0]` and other one is the button is out of the form tag but type is submit, where it shoud'nt be. since submit button always should be in <form> tag, so that whenever you click on it it'll submit the corresponding form. But in your case it is different as you are having two forms and you are handling forms with Javascript so here we dont need submit button. all you need is an event to execute the code which takes care of submission.

Answer (score -1):

```
function submitForms(){
    $('#form1_id')[0].submit();
    return false;

}
```

would submit your form effectively reloading the page.
First `return false` and then submit the form.

Comment: But I dont see the log message in the console after the change you suggested...I want to make sure it works because i will be submitting the data of multiple forms by a single button click using ajaxSubmit api from http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started